# D6 - Rule to simply redirect path to login

Tags: path-aliases, rules

Currently I'm trying to add create a rule that simply redirects anyone from /node/add to /user/login. It's intended to be part of a larger rule, but I'm having No luck with this

Steps of the rule are

1. Trigger - User is going to view a page
2. If path has alias(es) - /node/add
3. Do page redirect to - /user/login

Instead, it just goes to the /node/add page as usual. Why is this simple rule is not working?

Here is the rule exported.

```
array (
  'rules' => 
  array (
    'rules_30' => 
    array (
      '#type' => 'rule',
      '#set' => 'event_init',
      '#label' => 'Redirect to login if accessing /node/add',
      '#active' => 1,
      '#weight' => '0',
      '#categories' => 
      array (
      ),
      '#status' => 'custom',
      '#conditions' => 
      array (
        1 => 
        array (
          '#weight' => -1,
          0 => 
          array (
            '#weight' => 0,
            '#info' => 
            array (
              'label' => 'Path has alias(es)',
              'module' => 'Path',
              'eval input' => 
              array (
                0 => 'src',
              ),
            ),
            '#name' => 'rules_condition_url_has_alias',
            '#settings' => 
            array (
              'src' => 'node/add',
            ),
            '#type' => 'condition',
          ),
          '#type' => 'OR',
        ),
      ),
      '#actions' => 
      array (
        1 => 
        array (
          '#weight' => 0,
          '#info' => 
          array (
            'label' => 'Page redirect /user/login',
            'label callback' => false,
            'module' => 'System',
            'eval input' => 
            array (
              0 => 'path',
              1 => 'query',
              2 => 'fragment',
            ),
          ),
          '#name' => 'rules_action_drupal_goto',
          '#settings' => 
          array (
            'path' => '/user/login',
            'query' => '',
            'fragment' => '',
            'force' => 0,
            'immediate' => 0,
          ),
          '#type' => 'action',
        ),
      ),
      '#version' => 6003,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy option is to set the 403 Access Denied page at:

*admin/config/system/site-information*

to:

```
user
```

That way, if the user is not authenticated, they can login and view the node/add page.

I think the reason your Rule isn't working is because `/node/add` isn't an "alias" per se, but a system path.

Another option is something like

```
/**
 * Implements hook_init
 */
function MODULENAME_init(){
  if($_GET['q'] == 'node/add' && !user_is_logged_in()){
    drupal_goto('user/login');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution is available by using the [LoginToboggan](https://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module. WHen you configure LoginToboggan at `/admin/user/logintoboggan` simply Enable the option to *Present login form on access denied (403)*.

As far as the rule is concerned, `node/add` is a system path, not an alias, and it leads to the Add Content page. You might be able to get the rule to work if you use a data comparison on `node/add/*` but if the user does not have access I doubt the rule will trigger.